# Download, Revise, Upload Github Gists with R

Tags: git, r, github, rstudio, gist

I often find myself writing my R code in Rstudio and manually copying/pasting the code to a gist at [gist.github.com](http://gist.github.com).

I think Rstudio is great and they recently incorporated version control capabilities.  I haven't quite graduated to this level just yet, but I am hoping that I could link my github account and manage my gists in the same way. This would remove the manual actions that I take to save and retrieve my code snippets.

The key is that I want to be able to access my code across multiple locations and need to keep some of my code private.

Is this possible? Any help is greatly appreciated.

Comment: Not yet, but file a support request...

Comment: This seems like an RStudio feature request rather than a question, as with any editor without a plugin system or built-in support the only way to get external code into the editor is going to be cut and paste.  Managing the gists in a project using submodules is simple enough, but as 'snippets' it is all on the shoulders of the app developers or contributors to build.

Answer (score 2):

In regard to the private repos I think `github` only supports private repositories for paying users. If you want free private repositories, you could take a look at bitbucket which supports both Mercurial and Git repositories.

Answer (score 0):

You may find the `gistr` package useful.  You can read an introduction and see examples [here](https://docs.ropensci.org/gistr/articles/gistr.html).  Also, even shorter than the intro and examples here is a [2015 stack overflow answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/31616291/6850554) from the `gistr` package creator.