# Post a gist directly from R?

Tags: r, github, gist

I would like to find a simple way of putting gists on Github from R. Assume I have an object I want to convert into a gist. Normally I would save it as a text file and then upload it manually on Github. Is there a better way?

How can I create a gist directly from an R object and upload it to Github?

Comment: install : https://github.com/cscheid/rgithub & then use `github::create.gist`

Comment: I maintain a client for gists https://github.com/ropensci/gistr also on cran https://cran.rstudio.com/web/packages/gistr/ Should be a better experience than rgithub for gists

Answer (score 6):

I would suggest using my package `gistr` - which is built for working with GitHub gists. There are many ways you can create gists, including from files on your machine, or from R objects. You can knit .Rmd files during the creation process before uploading, etc. An example:

```
install.packages("gistr")
library("gistr")
file <- system.file("examples", "stuff.md", package = "gistr")
gist_create(file, description='a new cool gist')
#> <gist>974fd41ff30de9814cc1
#>   URL: https://gist.github.com/974fd41ff30de9814cc1
#>   Description: a new cool gist
#>   Public: TRUE
#>   Created/Edited: 2015-07-03T00:19:18Z / 2015-07-03T00:19:18Z
#>   Files: stuff.md
#>   Truncated?: FALSE
```

Comment: can this be used directly with `dput` as the question asks? It seems to fail for me: `gist_create(dput(sha_list), description='sha_list.R')`

Comment: So `dput()` just `cat()'s` a list to the R console, but what it gives as ouput is just whatever the input is to it, for example created this https://gist.github.com/sckott/35f0cf49b3763d8cec58 w/  `gist_create_obj(dput(mtcars))` - you can save output of `dput()` by setting a file name in the `file` parameter. Then use `gist_create()` with that file. `gist_create_obj()` is for R objects, while `gist_create()` is for files

Comment: @user:1091766: This does something weird to the file. For example, I try to redownload it using `library("devtools");
literal_strings <- source_gist("109be488a2413b403ba5");` but it doesn't work becaue instead of wrapping it in `c()` it wraps it using brackets `[]`.

Comment: Did you use `create_gist()` to make that gist?  If so, can you share reproducible code

Comment: Here's what I use to upload/download the gist: `x <- c("A", "B"); gist_create_obj(dput(x), filename = "x.R"); library("devtools"); literal_strings <- source_gist("a0ecb37dfc2c91bde394")`

Comment: The data that moves to and from the gist API is JSON, so you can easily parse that data using e.g., `jsonlite` jsonlite::fromJSON("https://gist.githubusercontent.com/aronlindberg/109be488a2413b403ba5/raw/9fdf47f475711e18d1c422f57fb21c97b86352d0/literal_string.R"). If you really want the R vector in the gist like `c(1, 2)`, I'd suggest using `gist_create()`, and pass in a file path